# Bootstrap Grid on the screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Bootstrap. I just created a sample web app using layoutit.com. When I do the preview on the website, the columns are aligned properly. I used md-2 and md-10, thereby dividing the screen into 2 layouts with 2 and 10. The first column with 2 grids, starts from the left most of the screen. Please refer the image-1  [image: Please refer the image-1]

When I downloaded the file and open it as an HTML file, then the first column with 2 grids, has more space on the left side. Even for second column with 10 grids also has more space to its right. Please refer the image-2.
[image]

**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Bootstrap 3, from LayoutIt!</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row clearfix">
  <div class="col-md-2 column">
   <ol>
    <li>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </li>
    <li>
     Consectetur adipiscing elit
    </li>
    <li>
     Integer molestie lorem at massa
    </li>
   </ol>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-10 column">
   <table class="table">
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>
       #
      </th>
      <th>
       Product
      </th>
      <th>
       Payment Taken
      </th>
      <th>
       Status
      </th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td>
       1
      </td>
      <td>
       TB - Monthly
      </td>
      <td>
       01/04/2012
      </td>
      <td>
       Default
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="active">
      <td>
       1
      </td>
      <td>
       TB - Monthly
      </td>
      <td>
       01/04/2012
      </td>
      <td>
       Approved
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="success">
      <td>
       2
      </td>
      <td>
       TB - Monthly
      </td>
      <td>
       02/04/2012
      </td>
      <td>
       Declined
      </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

***EDIT***

Code is attached for reference:

Please help me on why I am getting the empty spaces on the left and right of the columns. How to avoid that and use the page extensively.

Comment: Layout it adds divs(your md-10 and md-2) inside a container div by default. That is why you get the space on both sides. If you don't want it you can remove that container div(`<div class="container">`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have not provided code it will be hard to understand the problem in code. But what usually the problem comes is with using **container** class. So instead of using **container** class use **jumbtron** class or **container-fluid** class as they takes full width of the web page. For more clarification provide the code. Like this-

```
<div class = "jumbotron">
...
</div>
```

or

```
<div class = "container-fluid">
...
</div>
```

Comment: The style container-fluid satisfies the issue, but the container appears from first line of the page. What I mean is that, I have menus listed on the first row and the page header in the second row. The container actually starts in 3rd row (previous one).  But after changing it to container-fluid, the container starts from the first row hiding behind the menu and page header. Is there a way to tell the container to start from 3rd row?

Comment: Add two blank containers before the third one.

Comment: It worked. Thanks. Just one blank container fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using a class `container`, it provides a max-width for your page... If you don't want and want a full width, you can use `container-fluid`...

---

Replace your

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

by

```
<div class="container-fluid"></div>
```

Here is the [doc about container](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container)

Comment: The style container-fluid satisfies the issue, but the container appears from first line of the page. What I mean is that, I have menus listed on the first row and the page header in the second row. The container actually starts in 3rd row (previous one).  But after changing it to container-fluid, the container starts from the first row hiding behind the menu and page header. Is there a way to tell the container to start from 3rd row?